# How to merge partitons

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I have three operating systems: Windows 7, Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 12.10.

I have a primary partition and three logical partitions to Windows 7 (Localdisk C (primary), D, E and F). And I have one partition for Ubuntu 10.04 and another for Ubuntu 12.10.
But now I want to merge all the Windows partitions into one without losing any data or operating system. This is my partition table:

[image: Partition table]

And I want all ones in red merged into one. How can I do it?

Comment: **three** logical partiton to windows 7 (Localdisk **C** (primary), **D**, **E** and **F**) -- three... or four?

Comment: C is primary partition where I installed windows 7

Comment: Take a backup of your data, and wipe and install afresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can not merge them. You can back up the data from a partition, delete that partition, stretch c to fill the new free space, and then restore the data to the new larger c:. That will work for the two that are right next to c. You could also back up that lone partition, delete it, move its neighbor to its left into its space, expand c and restore to c. All these things can be done with gParted.

Comment: Be careful, I see you have a partition called softwares. Just moving its data to c will break some of your programs, and any links that were pointing to f (likely your entire start menu)

Comment: How can I move its neighbor to its left into its space

Comment: Just choose resize move and drag it to the right into the newly vacated space.